# HQL - join with only one subclasses

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, hql

My model (InheritanceType.JOINED):

> ```
> class Parent{...} 
> class Child1 extends Parent{...}   
> class Child2 extends Parent{...}
> class Child3 extends Parent{...}
> class Child4 extends Parent{...}
> class Agg{
>   List<Parent> l;
> }
> ```

Agg is connected with parent via join table. Parent don't have Agg object.

I am doing some filtering on Child2 i.e:
" From Child2 ch2 WHERE ch2.field1 =... ch2.field2 =... etc."

How can I now join Child2 with Agg, without causing join with all subclasses tables. 
I simple want to join only with Child2 table (without joining with Child2, Child3, Child4)

I was trying to use 'class' property (i.e. ch2.class =...) the result is correct, but generated query contains join to every subclasses ;/

HQL "From Agg a Join a.l" also join with all sub-classes (even with ch2.class)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have an "eager" loading on List<Parent> in Agg class, causing this. When you do a JOIN with a Parent class, you will be have this behavior (I never use Inheritance with Hibernate because of that). Can you provide more details, like the mapping of all classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross join to solve this since the DBMS will optimize this to an inner join anyway. Something like this `SELECT ch2, agg FROM Child2 ch2, Agg agg WHERE ch2.joinField = agg.id AND ch2.field1 =... AND ch2.field2 =...`